# if & else both printing... what am i doing wrong

Tags: python-3.x

Both the if and the else print() display as a result.
New to python and just need to get the basics right

Any help would be great.

```
if test_choice == '1':
    print("You have chosen to test Device & Softphone HTTP to Horizon")
    for port in '80':
        result = sock.connect_ex(('88.215.61.173', 80))
        if result == 0:
            print("Port 80 is open to xsp.unlimitedhorizon.co.uk")
        else:
            print("Port 80 timeout. Please check firewall")
```

if result == 0 and the else: both print as a result....

The result looks like this:

```
You have chosen to test Device & Softphone HTTP to Horizon
Port 80 is open to xsp.unlimitedhorizon.co.uk
Port 80 timeout. Please check firewall
```

Comment: Whats the `for port in '80':` supposed to do?

Comment: Ask yourself what happens when you `print` the value of `port` inside the for loop. Then test that assertion.

Comment: The second set of eyes does a dream. I don't need it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your for loop, port takes value '8' then '0'. Which something you dont want I guess.

Replace your for loop with

```
for port in ['80']:
     # Do Stuff
```

Port will only take one value ('80'), and so iterate only once

In your module, you need port to be an int. This is even better to do `for port in [80]`

Comment: Right on the money! I didn't realise that it would take the 8, and then take the 0, and run the loop on both. I was in the belief the '80' would denote 80 and not 8 & 0. 'for port in [80] worked fine

Comment: Also reading through some of the comments, I now realise i dont need it and can just have port 80 put into sock.connect_ex

Answer (score 1):

@BlueSheepToken is right, the loop `for port in '80':` makes the port variable to take `8` then `0` as values. This is because in [python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#text-sequence-type-str):

> Strings are immutable sequences

And sequences are [iterable](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterable).

So in the first run `result = sock.connect_ex(('88.215.61.173', 80))` connect successfully so result is equal to 0 that's why the first print is `Port 80 is open to xsp.unlimitedhorizon.co.uk`.
In the second run the connection is already establish so the `sock.connect_ex` fails and you get the second print.

So yeah you can to put your ports in a list if you really need to test multiple port but then you'll have to use the port variable too:

```
for port in [80]:
    result = sock.connect_ex(('88.215.61.173', port))
```

But if you only need to test one port you can just remove the for loop.

Comment: Perfect, makes lots of sense. I dont actually need "for port in [80]" unless I have more then 1 port to test in the loop.

Answer (score -2):

In that piece of code, you don't need that `for` (`for port in '80':`). Try to delete it.

Comment: While this maybe a valid point it doesn't provide a detailed answer to the original question and doesn't help to solve the problem, author would probably not have enough context to understand the implications of the loop here if they have it there in the first place

Comment: Correct, I don't need it. It was multiple ports at the start and has now reduced to one, so I can just input the port in 'result =' line